# How to always return a row when empty result and using the IN clause with arrays

Tags: postgresql

some help needed here. Am using PostgreSQL and given a query like the one bellow (this is parat of a more big query) I need it to ALWAYS return a row.

```
SELECT
    content,
    user_id,
    date,
    factor_id,
    team_id
FROM
    ANSWERS A
WHERE
    A.TEAM_ID IN ('7f4743df-5194-4ba4-8490-4b36ae63e27a', '8a4743df-5194-4ba4-8490-4b36ae63e27a')
    AND A.DATE >= '2020-10-22'::date
    AND A.FACTOR_ID IN ('0a577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e70d', '0f577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e54d')
ORDER BY
    USER_ID,
    DATE
```

Basically when it finds a combination  of team_id T and factor_id F where no results for the given dates, then I want it to return the actuals T and F items, the user_id and date, like this:

(null, '0000000-5194-4ba4-8490-000000000', '2020-10-22', '0a577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e70d', '0f577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e54d')

Is there any way when using the IN clause with array to return the it's iterating at the moment result was empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with an IN list.  You would have to use a VALUES list(s) and LEFT JOIN that to A.  Something like:

```
with b(team_id, factor_id) as (select * from (
   values ('7f4743df-5194-4ba4-8490-4b36ae63e27a'), ('8a4743df-5194-4ba4-8490-4b36ae63e27a'))t 
   cross join (
   values ('0a577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e70d'), ('0f577004-b283-410a-b245-bff019a8e54d'))f
)
SELECT
    content,
    user_id,
    date,
    b.factor_id,
    b.team_id
FROM
    b left join ANSWERS A on a.factor_id=b.factor_id and a.team_id=b.team_id and A.DATE >= '2020-10-22';
```

Now you show non-NULL being returned for user_id and date, but I don't where you expect them to come from. They can't from A if there is no row in A to pull them from, and can't come from the IN/VALUES lists as those don't contain them those fields.